# Jquery Input mask not visible with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I am using **RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask** to mask my input field.
I create below regex to validate it.

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}-.*
```

I used it as below in my input field.

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="abc" data-inputmask-regex="\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}-.*" value="" class="form-control" />
```

and initialized jquery code on document ready as below.

`$("#abc").inputmask('Regex');`

It was working and I can type only allowed characters in regex. but mask was not showing (mask on input field is not visible)

I want to validated/Mask below values

**99.99.99.99-(any character infinite lenght or optional text)**

Sample:

**12.20.26.52-abc; pqr. xyz2020**

How can I make it working for this regex. It should show mask on input field.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [regex extension page](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/blob/3.x/README_regex.md) , there's no placeholder for regexes :

> There is no further masking visualization.

You'll have to rely on `mask` to get masking helpers.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, placeholder for regex is not yet implemented.

> RobinHerbots commented on 15 Jan 2015
>   The regex alias currently
>   doesn't support a placeholder or any visual.

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/798

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to sort of spoof what you're looking for using a smattering of optional and dynamic sections with special mask definitions, but you will have to set some kind of character limit.

Something like the following should work - note that '100' is the technical maximum size of the overflow text here but could be increased.

```
$('#abc').inputmask({
     mask: "99.99.99.99[-*{0, 100}]",
     greedy: false,
     definitions: {'*': {validator: "."}}
 });
```

Incidentally, in my quick testing the repeat limit seems to be unenforced anyway (at least using version 3.3.4-128).

Answer (score -2):

According to the documentation, you have to add a placeholder like this:

`$("#abc").inputmask('Regex', { placeholder: "99.99.99.99-*" });`
(not tested)

Ref: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#placeholder-1